# Show line numbers in View mode

Tags: vifm

I've found that vifm's `number` option sets line numbers for the file list. I'd like to instead show line numbers for the preview window when it is visible  (`:view`). How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I think `:view` configuration depends on what program you use for viewing files.

Eg., if you use [highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/en/highlight.php), you could configure it like this in your `.vifmrc` file:

`fileviewer *.yml,*.json highlight -O xterm256 -l %c`

I didn't find a way to configure it for default fileviewer. The closest I got to is using `cat`:

`fileviewer *,.* cat -n %c`